# Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:

Tags: java, maven

Given the following:

```
> mvn clean compile
...
[ERROR] Failure executing javac,  but could not parse the error:
/bin/sh: c:/progra~1/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/javac: No such file or directory
```

checked that my `mvn` and `java` versions were correct:

```
$mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T07:57:37-04:00)
Maven home: /Users/kevin/Downloads/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

$java -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Unsure of a problem with my `brew`-installed `mvn`, I removed it and downloaded `mvn-...bin.zip` from [Apache](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi). Then I set my PATH, verified that `mvn -version` and `java -version` spit out the same versions. But, I'm still having the same problem.

I looked at the top 3 (from search) StackOverflow results, but have not gotten any further:

- [Maven compilation error. Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:javac: invalid flag: -s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733171/maven-compilation-error-failure-executing-javac-but-could-not-parse-the-error)
- [Maven, Failure executing javac: Compilation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956514/maven-failure-executing-javac-compilation-failure)
- [Compilation error: Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768702/compilation-error-failure-executing-javac-but-could-not-parse-the-error)

Comment: Maven thinks it's running Java 6 (for that project, anyway). Does that project have a specific JVM version it's meant to compile against?

Comment: In my case, a dependent project expected `jdk 1.6`. To fix this, I deleted my `~/.m2/repository/*` and then built the project with `mvn clean compile -Ddefault.java.version=1.7 -Ddefault.java.home=/usr/`

Answer (score 1):

You should check your *JAVA_HOME* variable or *pom.xml* for this  Windows-specific path: `c:/progra~1/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/javac` and change it to your real JDK installation path (`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre`?).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue when i started using a newer version of java.
In your case Maven is using java 6. Try setting JAVA_HOME environment variable to correct **JDK** version. I guess **JAVA_HOME** is pointing to jdk 1.6.